# Can I use a Seagate SSHD in my iMac and if so, how do I load OSX (High Sierra) onto it

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, fusion-drive, hdd

I'm looking to upgrade my iMac 14.2 (late 2013) by swapping out the existing HDD with a Seagate SSHD Hybrid drive, along with adding another 8Gb memory. I've done a similar upgrade on my daughter's iMac (same model) but used a SSD and it works great with major enhancement in speed. I would like to use a SSHD to save some money. Is there anything I need to do differently when installing a CLEAN version of High Sierra (I have already downloaded to a USB drive from the Apple APP store) onto the SSHD Hybrid?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use a Seagate SSHD on your 2013 iMac. 

Installing a new version of High sierra I would recommend formatting the disk to `APFS`, which is Apple's new optimised SSD & 'fusion' file format. Everything else will work fine.

The way the SSHD works is the SSD portion is just cached, and the **drive** itself manages what goes into the cache rather than the OS.

Seagate SSHD had some issues with the newer drive models in older macs, but that is mainly due to being a 3Gb/s SATA connector.

As your late 2013 machine has 6Gb/s SATA, any seagate drive `(Firecuda (new model) or momemntus (old model))` will be compatable.

You can read a little bit more into it on the [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208033) website, if you're interested in in-depth info.